# Bibliography heading left alignment

Tags: bibtex, horizontal-alignment

I am having following code, due to which the heading of bibliograpy/references is center align, if `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]` is removed then it is left justified but all the chapter heading is also left justified, I want chapter heading center align with bibliography heading left justified.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{5pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{5pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{5pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2 }
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{xyz}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just repeat the definition of `\chapter` omitting `\centering`must before the `\bibliography` instruction, that is:

```
...
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\LARGE}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{xyz}
```

By the way, adding  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}` after the bibliography produces a wrong result if the bibliography is longer than one page. It is better to use the `tocbibind` package to insert the bibliography/references in the table of contents